# Front-end Challenge Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, frontend

In a blog app, I want the `Next Comment` button to display the next (instance) comment once the user clicks on it.

I have the method defined and working in the `Comment` model, so my question is front-end oriented.

- How do I display the last comment dynamically? Meaning, that rails knows which comment it is and so it is able to display the next comment in line.
- How do I make it appear in the `%comment` html element? (AJAX?)

`welcome#index`:

```
- @articles.each do |article|
      .article
            %comment= article.comments.last.text
            = link_to "Next Comment", welcome_next_comment_path
```

`welcome_controller`:

```
class WelcomeController < ApplicationController

 def index
    ...
 end

 def next_comment
    find_comment
    article.comments.next(@comment)
 end

private 

 def find_comment
    ...
 end
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't tested it but it should work (give or take a few typos). At the very least it will guide you on how to accomplish what you wish

Your `Next Comment` link has the current comment id which gets passed when you click it in jQuery/ajax. The ajax method prevents the default behavior of visiting the link and fetches the precise part of the html page you're looking for (the comment on the page) and appends that to the container of the link that you clicked.

```
# app/controllers/welcome_controller.rb
  def next_comment
    find_comment
    @next_comment = article.comments.next(@comment)
  end


# app/views/welcome/next_comment.haml
#comment
  .article{id: "comment#{@next_comment.id}"}
    %comment= @next_comment.text
    = link_to "Next Comment", welcome_next_comment_path, data: {id: @next_comment.id, hook: 'comment-link'}


# your_view.haml
- @articles.each do |article|
  - comment = article.comments.last
  .article{id: "comment#{comment.id}"}
    %comment= comment.text
    = link_to "Next Comment", welcome_next_comment_path, data: {id: comment.id, hook: 'comment-link'}


# app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$("[data-hook='comment-link']").click(function(event)) {
  event.preventDefault();
  var url = $(this).attr('href');
  var id = $(this).data('id');
  var container = $('#comment' + id);
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: url,
    success: function(html) {
      container.append( $('#comment', html) )
    }
  });
});
```